# wordpress custom php function, simple question about calling variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Simple question, but couldn't find the answer.
When the function 'enkelpost'is called anywhere in WP the passed value($one_p) is gonne be the post ID displayed. But how to put this in the function itself. This is in the functions.php:

```
<?php
function enkelpost($one_p) 
{   

    query_posts('p= $one_p '); //how to make line this work?
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    global $more; $more = FALSE; 
    the_content('Read more...');
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

Lets say we want the singe post with id 150:

```
<?php enkelpost('150') ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not parsed when they are enclosed with single quote, put them in double quotes.

```
 query_posts("p= $one_p");
```

OR

Do not use quotes for variables at all

```
query_posts("p=".$one_p);
```

Comment: To simple. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this will be easier way!

```
<?php if (function_exists('enkelpost')): ?>
```